# System.Web.Providers vs aspnet_regsql

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to implement the system.web.providers Membership providers. Do I need to change my database and if so is there an updated aspnet_regsql tool available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system.web.providers automatically create the database on first use.